# Nginx and uWSGI stripping HTTP_AUTHORIZATION

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am working with an API and it seems that Nginx and uWSGI are removing the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header that I pass.

I send a curl POST to my API server which runs Django.  When I have Django print out a list of request.META I see that HTTP_AUTHORIZATION is missing.

Nginx config contains these:

```
uwsgi_pass_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION;
uwsgi_pass_request_headers on;
```

But doing these two passes doesn't seem to have any affect.

Any idea why there is this stripping... is it happening at the Nginx level, the uWSGI level, or the Django level?

Answer (score 5):

Try to change the underscore in `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` to a dash `HTTP-AUTHORIZATION` in your curl post.

Per default nginx marks headers with underscores as invalid and ignores invalid headers.

You can use nginx directives to either allow underscores in headers with `underscores_in_headers on;` or don't ignore invalid header with `ignore_invalid_headers off;`.

Comment: underscores_in_headers on; didn't work for me. but ignore_invalid_headers off; worked....Thanks. But is it ok to allow invalid headers?

Comment: its 1:30 am in India!! I want to thank you for this response I was frustrated for the last 5 hours. @elim thank you!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, and added the following settings to the location part of my nginx config:

```
uwsgi_pass_header Authorization;
uwsgi_pass_request_headers on;
```

Notice the value I used for `uwsgi_pass_header` is `Authorization`.

With these settings, my app to start receiving auth headers without warnings from nginx.

Comment: But option uwsgi_pass_header allows to pass RESPONSE headers, not REQUEST headers.